# No se cargan los datos en la etiqueta select usando materialize

Tags: jquery, html5, materialize

estoy enviando unos datos por jquery al html y este los envia. pero el select no los muestra creo que es por que uso un framework css llamado materialize y al no icializar el js del select de nuevo no carga los datos que envio.

```
success: function(respuesta){

                        var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);

                         for (i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {

                         console.log(obj[i].descripcion_necesidad);

                         $("#categoriaidea").append('<option>'+obj[i].descripcion_necesidad+'</option>');

                          }

                        }
```

esta parte es donde envio por jquery al html

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
                <select id="categoriaidea">
                  <option id="cargafoco" value="" disabled selected>Eliga una opcion</option>
                  </select>
                <label>Necesidad</label>
              </div>
```

aqui es donde quiero mostrar en el html. uso framework materialize

Answer (score 0):

resuelto por si alguien le sirve

```
  success: function(respuesta){

                        var obj = JSON.parse(respuesta);

                         for (i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {

                         console.log(obj[i].descripcion_necesidad);

                          $(document).ready(function() {

                         $("#categoriaidea").append('<option >'+obj[i].descripcion_necesidad+'</option>');
                         });

                          }

                           $(document).ready(function() {
                                 $('select').material_select();
                               });

                        }
```